# Hive Bucketing - How to run hive query for specific bucket

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have hive query which reads 5 large tables and outputs the records to next process. All these tables are partitioned on proc_dt and bucketed on user_id (5 buckets).  Joins are done on user_id and filtering on proc_dt.

How can I run this query for specific bucket of all the tables? For ex. I want to run the query for just first bucket of all tables.

The reason behind doing this is, once I complete the query for first bucket, I can send the output data to next process. While next process is running I can complete query for next bucket and so on. This way next process is not waiting for entire query to finish.

If I had one more column which had Mod5 of user ID, then I would have gone for partitioning. But there is no such column and I cannot add it.

Could anyone please give me some solution for this. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for it. We can mention the bucket number in join query. Check the below link for more detail.

https://www.qubole.com/blog/big-data/5-tips-for-efficient-hive-queries/

Comment: It is not correct to say that you can mention the bucket number in the join query. The link shows the table bucketed by itinid. The query does *not* mention the bucket number.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify partitions within query statements but not buckets. Buckets are used for optimization purposes - e.g. faster sampling and mapside joins. But they are not visible to sql statements.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables

So here is the documentation example:

```
CLUSTERED BY(user_id) INTO 256 BUCKETS;
```

This clearly does not permit access to individual buckets by value/name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestions. I cannot create partition on user_id column as it is unique and I cannot add any column to source tables. Is there any way I can achieve this requirement?

Comment: @kishor This is an answer to your original question - about how to query against buckets (which is not possible).